# How can I use awk in R

Tags: r, awk

I try to use awk to extract from a dataframe, but I get this message

```
    could not find function "awk"
```

Do I need to install a package?

Answer (score 2):

Awk is a system command you need to call out of your R environment to the operating system and execute the awk command.

Example from R console

```
> system( 'awk \'BEGIN { print "Hello, world" }\' ')
Hello, world
```

For future reference you may want to do a search in StackOverflow of related problems:

Search in StackOverflow for "R AWK"

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=R+AWK